# How to have a dynamically height adjusted textarea without constant reflows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, reflow

I'm currently doing something this for my React textarea component:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  let target = this.textBoxRef.current;

  target.style.height = 'inherit';
  target.style.height = `${target.scrollHeight + 1}px`; 
}
```

This works and allows the textarea to dynamically grow and shrink in height as line breaks are added and removed.

The problem is that on every text change there is a reflow occurring. This causes a lot of lag in the application. If I hold down a key in the textarea there is delay and lag as the characters are appended.

If I remove the `target.style.height = 'inherit';` line the lag goes away, so I know it's being caused by this constant reflow.

I heard that setting `overflow-y: hidden` might get rid of the constant reflow, but it did not in my case.

My only other idea is to do a scan of the textarea on every text change for the number of `\n` character counts and set the height based on that count. The only problem is that it seems brittle, verbose, and is an O(n) operation for every text-change that I'd like to avoid.

Thoughts?

Edit: Alright, I ended up just counting `\n`'s in the text change handler to predict the height. Contenteditable div's are too limited. Maybe I'll re-post this question later since I doubt it'll be re-opened.

Comment: target.style.height = 'auto';

Comment: Actually, I think I want to re-open this. `contentEditable` apparently has a large host of problems. It may just be easier to continue dealing with textareas.

Comment: Apparently doing even simple things with a `contentEditable` div is tricky and I rather not have to use a library with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to accommodate it: https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable

Answer (score 1):

You can use contenteditable div instead:

```
<div name="someName" contenteditable="true">This text can be edited by the user.</div>
```

Comment: I just tried this out and unfortunately it has its set of problems as well.. No placeholder text, can't set the text easily (need to use a dangerouslySetInnerHTML hack), updating the selection cursor is tricky, etc.